# Get VirtualPath of a View using ViewContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to figure out the current ViewContext's VirtualPath eg

~/Views/Company/Create.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
((WebFormView) ViewContext.View).ViewPath
```

Obviously this only works if your using the standard web form view engine (which based off the wording of your question, you are). I.e. the `ViewContext.View` returns an `IView`, which may not be a `WebFormView` if you're using a different view engine.

**Edit**: By the way, I have tested the above code and it definitely returns the path as a virtual path (and not an absolute or app relative path, like I initially assumed it might). I.e. it gives you a value like this:

```
~/Views/Company/Create.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the virtual path,

```
<%= HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath %>
```